# Is it possible to have 2 redmine versions running and using the same db?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, redmine

I am just curious, I have a stable redmine 1.3.2 and want to upgrade to 2.x. I go for a parallel install and I wonder if it is possible to have a parallel install using the same db.
Did anyone try that?

I have ubuntu 12.04

I use rvm to manage ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is NOT good idea.

I can predict following problems:

1. (fatal) they use different structure of DB. There are a number of new migrations for latest version. Some of new migrations can change structure extremely (for example remove/rename columns/tables). And I doubt that you will manage to start the second APP.
2. (critical) New version has own validation and it means that one APP can insert invalid records for another one.

I think it is enough to refuse idea to start two Redmines on one DB.

PS I beleive it is possible (but maybe not too easy) to upgrade code and DB with minimal losing data.